# Построение столбчатой диаграммы в lazarus

Tags: lazarus

Как обратиться к имени колонки в диаграмме Chart в lazarus?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, так:

```
Chart1.AxisList.Items[0].DislpayName
```

Comment: Я ввёл  Chart1.AxisList.Items[0]. и там нет параметра "Name". Вот что есть: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_29nlN8YoEHVU5BYVlkMkxsX1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ну вот, вам среда разработки подсказывает, что есть свойство `DislpayName`. Скорее всего это то, что вы ищите.